# mostrar datos de formulario

Tags: php, formularios

Tengo un formulario con su botón submit y quiero que despúes de hacer click me siga mostrando en el formulario los datos introducidos. Lo que hago con estos datos es guardarlos en un archivo .txt para utilizarlos despúes.
He pensado hacerlo guardándolo en una variable de sesión y que luego lo poga en el value pero no funciona.

```html
<?php
session_start();
echo '<form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"    value="'.if(isset($_SESSION["nombre"])){echo $_SESSION["nombre"];}.'">
      <input id="boton" type="submit" value="Guardar" >
    </form>';
```

Pero claro, falta pasar las variables de $_POST a $_SESSION y eso no sé cómo hacerlo. 
Supongo que será sencillo pero he estado buscando y aunque he encontrado cosas similares no he dado con la respuesta.
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Te has planteado enviar el formulario por AJAX? De esa manera te evitarías tener que guardar el estado del `<form>` antes del envío.

Comment: No lo he pensado porque no manejo AJAX. Ya lo siento. Algo pendiente. Gracias

Comment: Pues la única forma que veo posible que lo hagas, sin usar ajax, sería cogiendo los valores en javascript, asi qué, sí quieres te ayudo con lo de ajax, sino te muestro esa forma que te digo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tal ves esto te pueda ayudar.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"      value=".$_POST['nombre'].">
  <input id="boton" type="submit" value="Guardar" >
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funcion. pero sigo rizando el rizo: y ¿si es un select o un type=radio? por ejemplo?

Comment: Resuelto utilizando if para cada uno de los casos. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres seguir mostrando los datos al hacer clic en el botón de "Guardar", entonces esto te puede servir

```
<?php
$old_value = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : '';
echo '<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="'.$old_value.'">
    <input id="boton" type="submit" value="Guardar" >
    </form>';
```

Obviamente si vuelves a cargar de cero la página, se va a borrar el dato del campo.

Si quieres usar variables de sesión, este otro caso puede servir para mantener el valor en el campo, inclusive aunque recargues la página desde cero, a menos que lo cambies haciendo otro submit.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
    // Si se envia algo por POST, actualizar la variable de sesion
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $_POST['nombre'];
} elseif(!isset($_SESSION['nombre'])) {
    // La primera ejecución del script. La variable de sesion no existe, crearla
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = '';
} else {
    // Se recarga la pagina, pero la variable de sesión existe con un valor
    // No hacer nada
}
echo '<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="'.$_SESSION['nombre'].'">
    <input id="boton" type="submit" value="Guardar" >
    </form>';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funcionó y me quedaría con la de $_SESSION por ser más completo. Pero sigo rizando el rizo: y ¿si es un select o un type=radio? por ejemplo?